# Edit ‘JIRA Issues’ Macro , URL ---> fixVersion+%3D+6.0.0-beta3+ha1 gives syntax error

Tags: jira, confluence

While including JIRA issues Macro on my Wikipage, I am having this issue.

On Jira, for a list of tickets, I have put the the Fix Version = 6.0.0-beta3+ha1 .

By doing so whenever I try to add JIRA Issue, with the following url

http://rdtrack/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-xml/temp/SearchRequest.xml?jqlQuery=fixVersion+%3D+6.0.0-beta3+ha1&tempMax=1000

I get this message.

> The JIRA Issue was not able to process the search. This may indicate a problem with the syntax of this macro.....

What is my understanding is that symbol "+" in 6.0.0-beta3+ha1 is causing this issue. I search on the Internet and found that using special characters like "+, etc.", they should be used within '' or " ". Still using them does solve my issue and I cannot see the list of JIRA tickets using URL mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the `+` as it's a reserved character and remove the unnecessary one from your query.

`jqlQuery=fixVersion%3D6.0.0-beta3%2Dha1&tempMax=1000`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried what you suggested but still it did not work. You are rihgt in saying to remove the unnecessary reserved characters. Any way, thanks for the help. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Building on @rorschach's answer, try the following, which wraps quotes around the fixversion value (which is what you alluded to in your question).

```
jqlQuery=fixVersion%3D%226.0.0-beta3%2Dha1%22&tempMax=1000
```

Also, for a little bit more clarification on the `+`:
In JIRA, it does need wrapping in quotes... and in the URL, it's generally translated to a space.  That's why you need to escape the `+` in the URL, but still quote the escaped fixversion value.